# Need help looping through an excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to analyze some data from excel using python. I have imported my data using pandas. Some of my data has words like 'NA". For these I am trying to loop over and ignore them. How can I do that? Another column has words such as "I", IV" etc. and I am trying to do if statements such as if value = 'I' then (...) but it doesnnt seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('re_data.csv')

column = data['level']
score = data['scores']
for i in range(0, column.size):
    if column[i]='I' and score[i]<8.0:
        pass
    if score[i] = 'NA'
        pass
```

And I don't know how i'd load my sample data.
But Scores consists of numbers 1-10 and NA
levels contains values I-IV

Comment: Please post some example code, data, and expected output. Also look into `df.dropna` and `df.fillna`

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Comment: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('re_data.csv')

column = data['level']
score = data['scores']
for i in range(0, column1.size):
    if column[i]= 'I' and score[i] < 5.0:
        pass

Comment: So for level, I have values of I, II, III, IV

Comment: for i in range(0, column1.size):
    if score = 'NA':
        pass

Comment: Please edit these lines into your original question, and format as code (indent with 
4 spaces or highlight and press ctrl-K or cmd-K)

Comment: Fixed! Can't seem to share a piece of my excel file though

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in two parts:

- You are using `=` instead of `==`
- You are checking if score[i] is equal to the string 'NA'. But pandas converts 'NA' strings automatically to 'real' NA-values. So checking if it's equal to the string 'NA' wont'work.

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd
  data = pd.read_csv('re_data.csv')

  column = data['level']
  score = data['scores']
  for i in range(0, column.size):
      if column[i] == 'I' and score[i]<8.0:
          pass
      elif pd.isnull(score[i]):
          pass
  ```